# The SQLITE insert command show SIGSEGV error in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

This is my code that show me SIGSEGV error. But I can not find where is my mistake. When I copy exactly code to SQLite and run it, it works. but it shows me the SIGSEGV error in Qt IDE.
This is my code :

```
bool DB::InsertUserAuthenticate(int id,int Admin,int Active,int AT_ID,int UI_ID,QString UA_Data)
{
    QSqlQuery q;
    //begin transaction
    /*insert data if the exact data not repeated in table*/
    q.prepare("BEGIN; INSERT INTO UserInfo(UI_ID,UI_Admin,UI_Active)"
              " SELECT :id,:admin,:active"
              " WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UserInfo "
              " WHERE UI_ID=:id AND UI_Admin=:admin AND UI_Active=:active);"
              " INSERT INTO UserAuthenticate"
              " (AT_ID,UI_ID,UA_Data,UA_Active)"
              " VALUES (:atid,:uiid,:uadata,:active);"
              "COMMIT;");
             /* " VALUES (:id,:admin,:active);");*/
    q.bindValue(":id", id);
    q.bindValue(":admin", Admin);
    q.bindValue(":active", Active);
    q.bindValue(":atid", AT_ID);
    q.bindValue(":uiid",UI_ID);
    q.bindValue(":uadata",UA_Data);

    if(q.exec())
    {
        q.exec("COMMIT;");//finished the transaction
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        q.exec("ROLLBACK;");//bad finished. should rool back
        msg=q.lastError().text();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: does not give SIGSEGV here, what OS are you using? and on which line are you getting SIGSEGV??

Comment: I would use `QSqlDatabase::database().transaction()`, `QSqlDatabase::database().commit()`, `QSqlDatabase::database().rollback()` when dealing with transactions from Qt.

Comment: @Mike : q.lasterror() has that error. my OS is Linux.

Comment: what is msg? and where is it defined?

Comment: msg is global value. in string type.